# Connection lost whatever the long poll's settings with crossbar.io

Tags: websocket, long-polling, autobahn, crossbar

I'm using crossbar to test the websockets and the long polling.
But each time I try using long-polling as default transport, whatever the settings I set, I get a "connection lost" every 2 seconds in my console.
By the way, it works perfectly with the websocket.

Here's the settings I want to test:
On the server site:

```
{
  "lp": {
    "type": "longpoll",
    "options": {
      "request_timeout": 0,
      "session_tiemout": 0,
      "queue_limit_bytes": 0,
      "queue_limit_messages": 0
    }
  }
}
```

On the client side:

```
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
  transports: [{
    url: [my url],
    type: "longpoll",
    max_retries: 1, 
    initial_retry_delay: 1,
    retry_delay_growth: 3,
    retry_delay_jitter: 3
  }], ...
```

I'm using python on the server side, Chrome 43 as default browser (also tested on firefox).

Is something wrong in my settings ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I cannot replicate this. I'm using the longpoll example (https://github.com/crossbario/crossbarexamples/tree/master/longpoll) and have modified the config and the connection data to mirror what you list here. (I assume that the "tiemout" is just a typo here, since Crossbar.io doesn't start with this.)

This works fine in Chrome 43.

My best guess is that the problem is with something you didn't list.

My suggestion: Start from the example, and see whether this works for you.